# What to use instead of fig.canvas.get_tk_widget().update() in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, wxpython

If I only import the matplotlib library, I can use this statement to achieve my expectations. But now  matplotlib  is embedded in wxpython. Not only import matplotlib, but also

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

Obviously this method(`get_tk_widget().update()`) returns the Tk widget used to implement FigureCanvasTkAgg.But i use the frame in wxpython. So i want to know the function which reaches the same effects for wxpython.
What i have down is making the program pause by button or mouse click.The general resolution is as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
pause=False
def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause =not pause
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
while True:
        if not pause:
             ...doing codes...
        fig.canvas.get_tk_widget().update()
```

However,my fig  is 'FigureCanvasWxAgg' object, and has no attribute 'get_tk_widget'.So i am looking for another functions in wxpython.

Comment: What are "same effects"? What does `update()` do in TK that you need?

Comment: returns the Tk widget used to implement FigureCanvasTkAgg，and update the canvas

Answer (score 0):

Later, I found that the function 'onClick' was not called, I added a button to call.In addition,the function 'canvas.get_tk_widget().update()' 
 is replaced by 'FigureCanvas.draw()' and 'FigureCanvas.flush_events()'.The above is my solution.